# Relationship table not recognized in Laravel 5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have defined the following relationships to my models A & B:

**Model A**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class A extends Model {

protected $table = 'list';

public function b(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\B', 'id', 'id');

    }
}
```

**Model B**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class B extends Model
{

protected $table = 'project';

public function a(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\A', 'id', 'id');

}
```

}

I am trying to get the sum from the model B based on the selection from the model A. However, it returns an error as ***Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$b***

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $all = A::all()->count();
    $large = A::where('class', 'L')->count();
    $medium = A::where('class', 'M')->count();

    $lg = A::where('class','L')->get();
    $amount = $lg->b->sum('value');

    return view('srl')->with('large', $large)
                      ->with('medium',$medium)
                      ->with('all',$all)
                      ->with('amount',$amount);
}
```

The problem is in this line `$amount = $lg->b->sum('value');`. The relationship seems not working due to some reason. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get a relationship on a collection, the relationship exists on the objects (records) inside that collection. You need to loop over the `$lg` results, and for each one get their `b` values.

Something like this:

```
$lg = A::where('class','L')->get();
$amount = 0;
foreach($lg as $item)
{
    $amount += $item->b->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @James ... I had to double loop to get it work. I don't know why I had to loop it twice.